# in Rails ActiveRecord how do you specify the columns to select in a join created by has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails code that returns a left outer join based on a has_many relation:

```
@results = MyModel.where(:model_id => 123).includes(:foos).all
```

MyModel has this relationship:

```
 has_many   :foos, :as => :fooed, :conditions => 'foo_number IS NOT NULL', :order => "foo_number asc", :dependent => :destroy
```

This creates a Left Outer Join which selects all columns from the parent table (MyModel) and all columns from the child table (foos).

How can I choose which columns are selected in the child table for this join? I'm ok with either listing the columns to select, or the ones to ignore, so long as the resultant query does not include a particularly large column with lots of data. Filtering it out after the join is not an option in this case.

Ideally, I would like the result to still be the left outer join, instead of executing many SQL queries.

I've attempted:

```
@results = MyModel.where(:model_id => 123).includes(:foos).select("childcol1, childcol2").all
```

But this does not alter the generated query at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@results = MyModel.select('my.model.*, foos.childcol1, foos.childcol2').
                   where(:model_id => 123).
                   includes(:foos).
                   references(:foos)
```